# How to fix this (presumably) encoding-related error (Java, Gradle)?

Tags: java, gradle, encoding, automated-tests, gradle-2

I have the following method, which truncates a string to a certain size in bytes:

```
public class Utils {
    public static String trimStringToBytesSize(String s, int length) {
        if (s == null || length < 0) return null;
        int trimLength = Math.min(length, s.length());
        String trimmedString = s;
        while (trimmedString.getBytes().length > length && trimLength >= 0) {
            trimmedString = s.substring(0, trimLength);
            trimLength--;
        }
        return trimmedString;
    }
}
```

I wrote some tests for it:

```
@Test
public void trimStringToBytesSize() {
[...]
    trimStringToBytesSizeTestLogic("Шалом",
            6,
            "Шал"
    );
[...]
}

private void trimStringToBytesSizeTestLogic(final String input, final int
        stringLength, final String expectedResult) {
    final String actRes = Utils.trimStringToBytesSize(input, stringLength);
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult, actRes);
}
```

This test runs fine inside IntelliJ Idea. However, it fails when I run it in Gradle. The error is this:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<Шал[]> but was:<Шал[ом]>
```

Obviously, it has something to do with the byte sizes.

I tried to reproduce the problem in a [minimal project](https://github.com/dpisarenko/encoding_problem) , which contains the method and the test. The code is the same, but the problem, which appears in the original code does not appear in this minimal project.

I tried to find out the difference between them and compared the encodings in the minimal and the original project. The are the same according to Notepad++ (UTF-8).

What else could cause this test failure? How can I fix it?

Notes: I'm using Java 1.8 and Gradle 2.14 (I can't upgrade to a more recent version due to the requirements of the customer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the byte size of a string heavily depends on the encoding you use the generate the bytes from the string. As you use `String.getBytes()` without parameter, the default encoding is used. This is `UTF-8` on *nix systems and `ISO-8859-1' on Windows systems.

Your string `Шалом` in `UTF-8` bytes is `[-48, -88, -48, -80, -48, -69, -48, -66, -48, -68]`.
Your string `Шалом` in `ISO-8859-1` bytes is `[63, 63, 63, 63, 63]` which effectively is `?????`, because your characters cannot be encoded in `ISO-8859-1`.

So when your test is successful you have `UTF-8` as encoding, if it fails you have `ISO-8859-1` as encoding where there are only 5 bytes and thus the string is not touched.

You should almost never use methods like `String getBytes()` or `new String()` without specifying an explicit encoding, or you always have different behavior on different OS or in different contexts.